# How to save data in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, database, save

In the internet there are databases(mysql, oracle etc.) where I can send the informations submitted by the HTML input fields with PHP or any other server side language.

How is this working in C/C++? How can I let a user input something and them save the inputted value?

Comment: Did you have any particular database in mind?

Comment: Well, MySQL, Oracle etc... I edited my question.

Comment: I know C and a bit of C++. But what is C/C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

1. Make use of the standard file handling [functions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/File_IO)/[classes](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).
2. Embed a [tiny database](http://www.sqlite.org/).
3. Talk to a database server using [a standard interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity).

BTW, these are common for all languages.

Answer (score 3):

Really depends what you want to save.

There are libraries [(like this one)](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/) that will let you connect to SQL databases from C++.

Another approach would be to save/load it to a file. For simple things just [filestreams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/) may be good enough, other times you may want something a bit more hard-wearing like [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) to take some of the hard work out of it.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you thinking C/C++ is different than other languages (like PHP) concerning the storage of data?
You can save your data:

- in a database (need an Open Database Connection)
- in a tiny database such as SQLite
- in a file

You can choose the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

Are your talking about desktop(standalone) application or some web-app? And it depends on what type of information are you going to store. Perhaps, windows registry would be enough.

Also you can use MySQL for storing data. There are a lot of tutorials on how to work with MySQL via C++. Here's a  [convinient api](http://mysqlcppapi.sourceforge.net/).

And your should read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c.html).

Answer (score 2):

To let the user input something beyond the command-line you need a GUI toolkit. To communicate with databases you need a framework like MySQL Connector/C++.

Answer (score 2):

look also at the following: [libodbc++](http://libodbcxx.sourceforge.net/) - a C++ wrapper for ODBC, much more convenient than a plain C ODBC.

if you work on Linux, you may find useful info here: [UnixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) - The popular ODBC infrastructure for Linux.