# What is a common way of saving and retrieving simple data between a C program closing and restarting?

Tags: c, database, sqlite, save

There's a simple C application made using GTK+2.
It also has simple data on the interface, and the application needs to save the last used values before closing so that they can be loaded when the application starts again.

I found a few methods to save load data.

1. Saving a text file and load it.
2. Using a DB.

Since I'm a beginner with C, either way I need to do a RnD and start implementing.
I need to know the best/standard/effective method which is used by C programming professionals for this kind of scenario.

**Edit: Nature of data**

Data which need to be saved and retrieved are as follows.

- Several Double Values
- Several Char Values or Strings
- Few Boolean Values

Above data is used by the application to draw a diagram on the interface. When the application starts, it should draw the diagram using the old values.

Comment: I think the answer is (like many things in computing) "it depends". If it is a small amount of simple data then a file (text or binary) may do just fine. So unless the full description of the data and how it will be used is provided there isn't a single best answer to your question. For some further thoughts along those lines see [How to save data in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322794/how-to-save-data-in-c-c)

Comment: @kaylum More details added.

Comment: There are endless variations on the theme.  You could argue that documents such as PDF files, or LibreOffice/OpenOffice/Microsoft Office documents are examples — and fiendishly complex ones at that.  People have endless sets of configuration files; your data could be part of a configuration file.  You could save it in a separate file. The format could be simple text, or JSON, or XML, or almost any variation. If you have a formal DB around for use with the application, then storing the data in that might make sense. You probably should be using a fairly simple text format for what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The straightforward way**

The easiest way would be to put the variables you want to store in a `struct`. Then you can output/load the content of the struct in/from a file (in binary mode). The pro of this technique is that you do not have to go through all your variables. I would definitely go for this solution if you can close your program properly.

**Checkpoint/Restart libraries**

In High Performance Computing, when launching a simulation code which takes a long time to execute (or/and using a large amount of compute nodes), it is quite common to use checkpoint/restart libraries. 
If there is a failure, the program may be restarted from the previous valid checkpoint. It is used more often when something may go wrong during the execution.